# Apache HTTP Client Spring Application Context XML for Version 4.3.1

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat7, applicationcontext

I am trying to Spring inject org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig. I am trying to set the default number of connections, max connections and soTimeout values. We are using apache version 4.1,1.

While spring initialization, I get an error indicating soTimeout and tcpNoDelay are not writable properties. From all my Google searches, I see that these properties should be writable. Can someone help me understand HTTP Client Initialization on Apache 4.3.1

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="dispatcherHttpConnectionManager" class="org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager">
<!-- property name="params" ref="dispatcherHttpConnectionParams" /-->
<property name="maxTotal" value="1000" />
<property name="defaultMaxPerRoute" value="50" />
<property name="defaultSocketConfig" ref="apacheSocketConfig" />
```

### **Error:**

Authentication/authorization failed with error `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dispatcherHttpConnectionManager' defined in class path resource [dispatchClientApplicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'apacheSocketConfig' while setting bean property 'defaultSocketConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apacheSocketConfig' defined in class path resource [dispatchClientApplicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'soTimeout' of bean class [org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig$Builder]: Bean property 'soTimeout' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`

Comment: My application context is too long for the comment. Someone knows how I can post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but...

You need to use SocketConfig.Builder (http://javadox.com/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3/org/apache/http/config/SocketConfig.Builder.html) to construct the SocketConfig bean:

```
<bean id="socketConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig" factory-method="custom">
    <property name="soTimeout" value="1000" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="connectionManager" class="org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager">
    <property name="defaultSocketConfig"><bean factory-bean="socketConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" /></property>
</bean>
```